# How to pass string variables to labels option in Morris.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, morris.js

I am using Morris.js for rendering charts in Rails project. There is a problem that I have no idea how to pass values from JSON string to labels option in Morris.js.

Below are contents from a helper method:

```
def worst_yield_chart_data(reports)
  start_time = reports.last.published_at
  end_time = reports.first.published_at
  datetime = Report.where("config = ? AND published_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 'ALL', start_time, end_time).select("distinct(published_at)")
  datetime.map do |date|
    {
      published_at: date.published_at.to_datetime.to_formatted_s(:long),
      # Top1 worst yield rate & station name
      worst_accu_yield: Report.group_accu_yield_by_date(date.published_at).first.try(:worst_accu_yield),
      worst_daily_yield: Report.group_daily_yield_by_date(date.published_at).first.try(:worst_daily_yield),
      worst_accu_yield_station: Report.group_accu_yield_by_date(date.published_at).first.try(:station_name) || 'No Input',
      worst_daily_yield_station: Report.group_daily_yield_by_date(date.published_at).first.try(:station_name) || 'No Input',
      # Top2 Worst yield rate & station name
      worse_accu_yield: Report.group_accu_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(2).first.try(:worst_accu_yield),
      worse_daily_yield: Report.group_daily_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(2).first.try(:worst_daily_yield),
      worse_accu_yield_station: Report.group_accu_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(2).first.try(:station_name) || 'No Input',
      worse_daily_yield_station: Report.group_daily_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(2).first.try(:station_name) || 'No Input',
      # Top3 worst yield rate & station name
      bad_accu_yield: Report.group_accu_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(3).first.try(:worst_accu_yield),
      bad_daily_yield: Report.group_daily_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(3).first.try(:worst_daily_yield),
      bad_accu_yield_station: Report.group_accu_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(3).first.try(:station_name) || 'No Input',
      bad_daily_yield_station: Report.group_daily_yield_by_date(date.published_at).offset(3).first.try(:station_name) || 'No Input'
    }
  end
end
```

The view contents as below:

```
= content_tag :div, "", id: "worst-accu-yield-data", data: {reports: worst_yield_chart_data(@reports_for_cart)}
```

And the javascript codes in HAML file is like below:

```
:javascript
  jQuery(function() {
    Morris.Bar({
      element: 'worst-accu-yield-data',
      resize: true,
      hideHover: 'auto',
      continuousLine: true,
      data: $('#worst-accu-yield-data').data('reports'),
      goals: [90, 95.5, 100],
      goalLineColors: ['#e74c3c', '#e67e22', '#2ecc71'],
      xkey: 'published_at',
      ykeys: ['worst_accu_yield', 'worse_accu_yield', 'bad_accu_yield'],
      labels: ['worst_accu_yield_station', 'worse_accu_yield_station', 'bad_accu_yield_station'],
      trendLine: true,
      postUnits: '%',
      ymin: 'auto',
      ymax: 'auto',
      parseTime: false,
      barColors: ['#cb4b4b', '#f8aa33', '#1fbba6'],
      barOpacity: 0.7,
      behaveLikeLine: true
    });
```

The purpose is to get Top3 Worst station name with its' yield rate in bar cart.
I am able to get string values in "xkey" and "ykeys" correctly. 
Also, I would like to pass each station's name to label option in morris.js (ex: **Station A**, **Station B**, **Station C**).
But in this case, it shows hardcoded string for me: **worst_accu_yield_station**, **worse_accu_yield_station**, **bad_accu_yield_station**.

[My Bar Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA8po.png)

Is it possible to pass each station name to label option? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: While you map your data, is it possible to save the station names you need to a new array and then pass that array to the `labels` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by customizing the hover option.

```
"hoverCallback":  function(index, options, content){
    var row = options.data[index]
    datetime = '<p><b>' + row.published_at + '</b></p>'
    station1 = '<div style="color: #cb4b4b;">Worst: ' + row.worst_accu_station + ' (' + row.worst_accu_yield + '%)</div>'
    station2 = '<div style="color: #f8aa33;">Worse: ' + row.worse_accu_station + ' ('  + row.worse_accu_yield + '%)</div>'
    station3 = '<div style="color: #1fbba6;">Bad: ' + row.bad_accu_station + ' ('  + row.bad_accu_yield + '%)</div>'
    return [datetime, station1, station2, station3]
  },
```